# How can I redirect the output of Perl's system() to a filehandle?

Tags: perl, fork, io-redirection

With the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) command in Perl, you can use a filehandle. However I have trouble getting back the exit code with the open command in Perl.

With the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command in Perl, I can get back the exit code of the program I'm running. However I want to just redirect the STDOUT to some filehandle (no stderr).

My stdout is going to be a line-by-line output of key-value pairs that I want to insert into a mao in perl. That is why I want to redirect only my stdout from my Java program in perl. Is that possible?

Note: If I get errors, the errors get printed to stderr. One possibility is to check if anything gets printed to stderr so that I can quite the Perl script.

Comment: What you have tried? any code.

Comment: I have. The closest I've gotten is with the open function. Ideally it would be great to get the exit code from my Java program with the open function in Perl.

Comment: Octopus was asking to see example code which shows what you've tried. We can't tell you what's wrong with your code if we haven't seen it.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::System::Simple) -- it gives you many options for executing external commands, capturing its output and return value, and optionally dying if a bad result is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Canonically, if you're trying to get at the text output of a forked process, my understanding is that's what the backticks are for. If you need the exit status as well, you can check it with the `$?` special variable afterward, e.g.:

```
open my $fh, '>', "output.txt" or die $!;
print {$fh} `echo "Hello!"`;
print "Return code: $?\n";
```

Output to STDERR from the command in backticks will not be captured, but will instead be written directly to STDERR in the Perl program it's called from.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways to do it.

```
open my $fh, '>', $file;
defined(my $pid = fork) or die "fork: $!";
if (!$pid) {
    open STDOUT, '>&', $fh;
    exec($command, @args);
}
waitpid $pid, 0;
print $? == 0 ? "ok\n" : "nok\n";
```

Comment: don't forget to close `$fh`!

Comment: ...and to restore STDOUT?

Answer (score 1):

Use `open` in `-|` mode. When you `close` the filehandle, the exit status will be in `$?`.

```
open my $fh, '-|', "$command";  # older version:  open my $fh, "$command |";
my @command_output = <$fh>;
close $fh;
my $command_status = $?;
```

From [`perldoc -f close`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#close)

> If the file handle came from a piped open, `"close"` will
>   additionally return false if one of the other system calls
>   involved fails, or if the program exits with non-zero status.
>   (If the only problem was that the program exited non-zero, `$!`
>   will be set to 0.)  Closing a pipe also waits for the process
>   executing on the pipe to complete, in case you want to look at
>   the output of the pipe afterwards, and implicitly puts the exit
>   status value of that command into `$?` and
>   `"${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}"`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the question was on how to redirect a command's output to an already opened filehandle, not how to capture it.

Comment: @codeholic - strictly speaking, the second sentence of the OP expresses interest in getting the exit code back from an `open` statement. The OP recognized there are many ways to accomplish this task and did a good job of avoiding a 'How do I use X to accomplish Y?' type of question.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no interest in `open` in the second sentence. The exit code just should have been got, and it doesn't matter how.